# Delete items from ListBox in WPF?

Tags: wpf, listbox

I am trying to delete items from listbox which is data bound. 
Here is the screenshot how listbox look like.

[image]

This is the code which adds items in lists.

```
    public class Task
    {
        public string Taskname { get; set; }

        public Task(string taskname)
        {
            this.Taskname = taskname;
        }
    }

    public void GetTask()
    {
        taskList = new List<Task>
                           {
                               new Task("Task1"),
                               new Task("Task2"),
                               new Task("Task3"),
                               new Task("Task4")
                           };

        lstBxTask.ItemsSource = taskList;
    }
```

This is the Xaml code,

```
 <ListBox x:Name="lstBxTask" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxItems}" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>                
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Taskname}"  Style="{StaticResource TextInListBox}"/>
                    <Button Name="btnDelete" Style="{StaticResource DeleteButton}" Click="btnDelete_Click">
                    </Button>                        
                </StackPanel>                    
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Whenever item in a listbox is selected, delete (x) button is displayed. When clicked it should delete that item from the listbox. Can anyone tell me how can I do this?

Comment: Try searching StackOverflow. You may find loads of answers involving DataContext, VisualTreeHelper, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using an ObservableCollection<T> instead of a simple List<T>.

The ObservableCollection<T> will notify the WPF-binding-system whenever its content has changed. Therefore, you will only have to remove the item from the list and the UI will be updated.

Answer (score 11):

ok this is what i did. Observablecollection worked like charm.

```
private ObservableCollection<Task> taskList;

public void GetTask()
        {
            taskList = new ObservableCollection<Task>
                               {
                                   new Task("Task1"),
                                   new Task("Task2"),
                                   new Task("Task3"),
                                   new Task("Task4")
                               };

            lstBxTask.ItemsSource = taskList;
        }

 private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var button = sender as Button;
            if (button != null)
            {
                var task = button.DataContext as Task;

                ((ObservableCollection<Task>) lstBxTask.ItemsSource).Remove(task);
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
```

Comment: +1 You can remove the task directly from taskList like this `taskList.Remove(task);`. Also the else part is not required.